# Touchpad problems since update to UU. Cannot highlight words

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Ever since I updated to 14.10. I have experienced some problems with the functions of the touchpad on my Acer E3-112.

Whenever I press and hold the left mouse (touchpad) button next to a word to highlight it by dragging the cursor across it, the cursor gets 'stuck' and I am unable to move it.

I'm also under the impression, that the buttons I click on the touchpad are often not being recognized correctly (i.e. option menu opens when I use the left touchpad-button instead of opening the application).

Is this a known issue in 14.10? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try re-installing mouse & touch drivers form software center.